# What will be the output of following C program and how?

Tags: c, escaping, backslash

What wil be the output?
 I am confused of the `\\` . How does it work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    printf("\\nab");
    printf("\\bsi");
    printf("\\rha");
}
```

Comment: You tried to compile and execute it? In that case, what was the result and what do you expected?

Answer (score 1):

The output will be `\nag\bsi\rha`.
The string `"\\"` converts to literal `"\"`.

That is because `\n` symbolizes a new line, and there are several other uses for the single char `\`. If it didn't work this way, there would be no way to print the literal `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will be:

```
\nab\bsi\rha
```

1 - The three text are printed together because you are using `printf` without an escape character `\n`, if you instead use

```
...
printf("\\nab\n");
printf("\\bsi\n");
printf("\\rha\n");
...
```

You will get

```
\nab
\bsi
\rha
```

In the first print you are writing `\n` and this means a new line, but you are declaring two slashes that indicate to print 'as is' a single slash (in C to print a slash you must be use \\ (two) because a single slash is pretended to use for special escape characters like \n).

Try to execute the your original with it to see the main difference:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  printf("\nab\n");     /* Note that I am using a escape character \n to make a new line after each print */
  printf("\bsi\n");
  printf("\rha\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, If this `\`is used before special characters, it is called an escape literal. What this does is, remove the functionality of special characters right infront of it.
Ex: Incase you want to print this line in output : `Hi this, ", is a quote symbol`. You would write it as : `printf("Hi this, \", is a quote");`

Similarly for escape sequences such as \n \t \b, to remove the special characte `\` from it would require an escape literal.